# Examples of classes used to represent html controls in a wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, wcf, webforms

I am writing a wcf service which will generate html controls which the client application will use to render part of a web page - for example a html select populated with list of options. The service will be written in C# (.net framework v4), in my implementation the client application will be a C# asp.net web forms application.

I would like the service to provide the html controls in a structured format rather than just a string of html so that the client application will be able to use them more flexibly (for instance the client application might want to add another option to a html select control)

In the past I have used classes the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace within an asp.net application for this purpose, but these classes cannot be serialized so I have not been able to use them with wcf. At the moment I only have the requirement to send select and text input controls, but rather than re-inventing the wheel I hope that someone will have an example of a service that already provides html controls in a structured format.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WCF I would use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and Razor view engine to generate HTML.